# What is the replacement for navigationOptions in react navigation 6?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react navigation 6 but there is no navigationOptions like react navigation 3 and 4. So I want to know is there any alternative in version 6 to use navigationOptions.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stacks navigation you can use **screenOptions**

Here is the code of Stack

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  screenOptions={{
    headerMode: 'screen',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'tomato' },
  }}
>
```

Further you can check [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) for Tab and Drawer and also check the Documentation [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)